# How can I use a 5V pwm with a 12V pwm

Tags: electrical-engineering, pwm

I'm trying to control my 12V fan with a 5V fan controller.
With this circuit the fan run at full speed.
When I measure the voltage on PWM and ground I obtain 5V.

Which circuit can I use to adapt the 5V PWM on the 12V PWM ?

[image: schema]

Comment: Can you please share the 5V fan controller and and 12V Fan electrical specifications?

Comment: The fan is [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Slim-DC-12V-Brushless-Cooling-case-Fan-Chassis-DC-Fans-92mm-x92mm-x15mm-4pin-New/172568279255?hash=item282ddef8d7%3Ag%3A1LYAAOxySoJTUIoh&_sop=15&_sacat=0&_nkw=92mm+fan+slim&_from=R40&rt=nc) and the fan controller is a classic [4 pin fan header](https://allpinouts.org/pinouts/connectors/motherboards/motherboard-cpu-4-pin-fan/)

Comment: I recommend that you update body of the question with ` ebay` and `4 pin fan header` information. Also do you want to dynamically control the PWM signal, or just have static PWM signal.

Comment: Hi - I think you'll get more useful answers over at Electronics.SE

Comment: @zedzedz7efzze, thank you for the additional information. I suggest you update the body of question with this new information to help attract alternate responses. Also if you are satisfied with the responses I suggest accepting the current answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on provide information I suggest taking a look at [ADT7467 dbCOOL Remote Thermal
Monitor and Fan Controller](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/ADT7467-D.PDF)

The image below should help on to configure the circuits.

[image: ADT7467 circuit configuration -1]

Depending on the FAN specification a pullup to 3.3V, 5V or 12V might also be required.

[image: ADT7467 circuit configuration Pull up]

Alternatively I would recommend looking at something like the following.

[Newest Black PC 1 to 10 PWM 4Pin Cooler Cooling Fan Hub Splitter Cable Power by 12V SATA Power Supply Adapter For PC Mining](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIACJF6HF8769&cm_re=fan_speed_controllers-_-9SIACJF6HF8769-_-Product)

[image]

With reference to 4-wire Specifications, I found a 2004 CPU fans specification from Intel. It is assumed that the your fan specification are similar. The full specification is attached in the reference section.

[image: Intel 4-wire Fan Specification]

I hope this helps you.

**References:**

- [Three-wire and four-wire CPU fans, what's the difference?](https://superuser.com/questions/1126136/three-wire-and-four-wire-cpu-fans-whats-the-difference/1126155)
- [Troubleshooting PCB of an ATX power supply?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/176061/50587)
- [4-Wire Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) Controlled Fans](https://folk.uio.no/kyrrens/diverse/viftekontroller/developer-specs-REV1_2_Public.pdf)

Comment: @zedzedz7efzze I sorry I am unsure on what you want to achieve. But I hope this helps to get started. Also do you have a electrical specification of the FAN, a part number, manufacture etc.